# c# using filename to match database value with existing file in directory

Tags: c#, .net-2.0

i am writing a console app in c# to check if file 'id' in sql server table matches filename of  file on local directory...i know how to use filename to check a location(all this does is check file exists in local directory)...

for example if there was an entry in a sql table of value '925677bb-cabb-4ff1-8c90-3e130a77b366'...i would want to perform check on location (c:\...) where any files with that filename would exist, ie '925677bb-cabb-4ff1-8c90-3e130a77b366.jpg'

what would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [`File.Exists`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx) function:

```
string id = ... go and fetch from your db
string filename = Path.ChangeExtension(Path.Combine(@"c:\somefolder", id), ".jpg");
if (File.Exists(filename))
{
    // the file c:\somefolder\925677bb-cabb-4ff1-8c90-3e130a77b366.jpg exists
}
```

Comment: ok that might work...just one thing, for the line 'string id = ... go and fetch from your db' would this just be my SELECT query or would an actual FETCH be required? Thanks

Comment: That would be a call to some method that will retrieve the value from your database. If you use plain ADO.NET then, yes you will write the SELECT statements, but if you are using an ORM such as Entity Framework for example to access your database all you need to do is query your data context.

Comment: hey darin, thanks again. I am using an ado.net select...ie SELECT ID FROM tblEXTRec Where Proccessed = ('false')...how would that read in your above example? thanks

Comment: @omarlittle, are you having problems using ADO.NET to query a relational database? I think there is sufficient information on the internet for you to get started. Hint: Google for `ADO.NET` and `SqlConnection` and start reading.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of [Directory.GetFiles()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx), like this

```
string []files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\", "925677bb-cabb-4ff1-8c90-3e130a77b366*.jpg")
```

in this way you will get all files that **starts** with specified string in C:\ directory

So if the array `files`  is empty, there is no any file like that, otherwise, there is at least one.